# can the abbreviation for "Schedule" be used for "scheduled"?

Tags: abbreviations

I read in [writing explained.org](https://writingexplained.org/english-abbreviations/schedule) that "schedule" can be abbreviated as Sched or Skd.

Can these abbreviations be used for "Scheduled"? (as in a task scheduled for 5.30pm)

Any suggestions for abbreviations for *Scheduled* will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don’t know where you read that, but I’d avoid using “Skd” for _schedule_ or _scheduled_. It doesn’t seem to be very [prevalent](https://www.acronymfinder.com/SKD.html).

Comment: I found it here https://writingexplained.org/english-abbreviations/schedule

Comment: I have been reading and writing English for about 40 years, and I don't think I have ever once seen *schedule* abbreviated as "Skd".  It might be in use only within certain fields.

Comment: Not all dialects of English pronounce the word "schedule" with a /k/ sound. For that reason, a BrE speaker might not recognize "Skd" even in context.

Comment: @CanadianYankee wow, how do british pronounce schedule? (interested)

Comment: Basically, "shed-jule".  The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/schedule) has some sound clips.

Answer (score 4):

"Sched." could be used for scheduled. Almost any word can be abbreviated by shortening it, given sufficient context, but ask yourself is it really important to save those few letters.

Any form of abbreviation will harm readability. The word "scheduled" appears as part of a sentence. I can't see much benefit in writing (for example) "meeting sched. at 4:30". I wouldn't use the abbreviation as part of a paragraph.

I've never seen *skd* as an abbreviation, even though I pronounce the word as *skedule*. It would seem to be even less likely where *shedule* is the pronunciation.